# Replace 'A' to 1, 'B' to 2, in R dataframe column

Tags: r

We have a column of a dataframe with letters A to Z

```
df$Col1 <- c("B", "C", "Q", ... , "A")
```

I want to change those letters to numbers 1-26.

Naturally I could just do the following 26 times, but it isn't efficient nor pretty.

```
df$Col1  <- gsub("A","1",df$Col1)
```

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` and the built-in constant `LETTERS`:

```
Col1 <- c("B", "C", "Q", "A")

as.character(match(Col1, LETTERS))
#> [1] "2"  "3"  "17" "1"
```

Comment: Thank you! One interesting point of this solution is that if Col1 has a value that is not in LETTERS we get an NA, as that is the default in the match function. In my case I had some values that were already in the right format
Col1 <- c("B", "9", "Q", "A")
So I applied your solution in a different column and then used coalesce to get them back together!

Answer (score 2):

For fun:

```
sapply(Col1, utf8ToInt, USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 64
[1]  2  3 17  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this in base R is to create a lookup table.

```
LookUp = 1:26
names(LookUp) = LETTERS
Replacement = LookUp[Data]
```